# An integral of the form $\int_{t_1}^{t_1 + \frac{2 \pi}{\omega}}\cos( i \omega t) \cos (j \omega t) dt $

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I decided to recall that integrals of the form

$\int_{ -\pi }^{ \pi} \cos( m t) \cos (n t) dt $ 0 if m $\neq$ n or $\pi$ if n $=$ m , I think

and

$\int_{ -\pi }^{ \pi} \sin( m t) \sin (n t) dt $ 0 if m $\neq$ n or $\pi$ if n $=$ m , I think  also

I had the epiphany to try to recall these after my computer spouted strange things at me when I tried giving it those integrals.

At any rate, the integrals below popped up during a calculation and I was wondering if there is some identity I should know about. I feel like there is something in an integration table somewhere that will give me the answers to these.

$\int_{t_1}^{t_1 + \frac{2 \pi}{\omega}} \cos( i \omega t) \cos (j \omega t) dt $

$\int_{t_1}^{t_1 + \frac{2 \pi}{\omega}} \sin( i \omega t) \sin (j \omega t) dt $

Here i and j are just constants.

Comment: Is i,j real? Or do they represent complex numbers?

Comment: i,j are real. They are not the imaginary i and j.

Comment: Ok, then you can use the following formula: for any periodic function f(x) with period T, $$\int_a^{a+T}f(x)dx=\int_0^T f(x)dx$$ and if n is any positive integer, then $$\int_a^{a+nT}f(x)dx=\int_0^{nT} f(x)dx$$

Comment: The integrand has period $2\pi/\omega$ so you can just set $t_1\to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the identity
$$\cos \theta \cos \varphi = {\cos(\theta - \varphi) + \cos(\theta + \varphi) \over 2}$$
So (for $i \ne j$ both integers)
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_1 + \frac{2 \pi}{\omega}} \cos( i \omega t) \cos (j \omega t) dt = \frac12\int_{t_1}^{t_1 + \frac{2 \pi}{\omega}} \cos( (i-j) \omega t)  + \cos( (i+j) \omega t)\,dt  $$
$$=\frac12 \left[ \frac{\sin( (i-j) \omega t)}{(i-j)\omega } + \frac{\sin( (i+j) \omega t)}{(i+j)\omega }\right]_{t_1}^{t_1 + \frac{2 \pi}{\omega}}$$
$$=0$$
and $i=j$ an integer:
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_1 + \frac{2 \pi}{\omega}} \cos^2( i \omega t)  dt = \frac12\int_{t_1}^{t_1 + \frac{2 \pi}{\omega}} \cos( 2i \omega t)  + 1\,dt  $$
$$=\frac{ \pi}{\omega}$$

Comment: Why do i, j have to be integers?

Comment: @Kevin Njokom If $i$ and $j$ are real numbers, not necessarily integers , then this answer is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t_1, i, j, w \in \mathbb{R}$ and let the given integral be $I$. Then

$$
\eqalign{
I &= \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{1}+\frac{2\pi}{w}}\cos\left(iwt\right)\cos\left(jwt\right)dt \cr
&= \frac{1}{w}\int_{wt_{1}}^{w\left(t_{1}+\frac{2\pi}{w}\right)}\cos\left(iu\right)\cos\left(ju\right)du \cr
&= \frac{1}{w}\int_{wt_{1}}^{w\left(t_{1}+\frac{2\pi}{w}\right)}\frac{\cos\left(\left(i+j\right)u\right)+\cos\left(\left(i-j\right)u\right)}{2}du \cr
&= \frac{1}{2w}\int_{wt_{1}}^{w\left(t_{1}+\frac{2\pi}{w}\right)}\cos\left(\left(i+j\right)u\right)du+\frac{1}{2w}\int_{wt_{1}}^{w\left(t_{1}+\frac{2\pi}{w}\right)}\cos\left(\left(i-j\right)u\right)du. \cr
}
$$

From here, We will make two cases. I will warn you that these cases do not result in a pretty answer.

*Case 1.* If $i \neq j$, then

$$
\eqalign{
I &= \frac{1}{2w\left(i+j\right)}\int_{w\left(i+j\right)t_{1}}^{w\left(i+j\right)\left(t_{1}+\frac{2\pi}{w}\right)}\cos\left(v\right)dv+\frac{1}{2w\left(i-j\right)}\int_{w\left(i-j\right)t_{1}}^{w\left(i-j\right)\left(t_{1}+\frac{2\pi}{w}\right)}\cos\left(x\right)dx \cr
}
$$

$$
= \frac{\left(i-j\right)\sin\left(\left(i+j\right)t_{1}w+2\pi i+2\pi j\right)+\left(-i-j\right)\sin\left(\left(j-i\right)t_{1}w-2\pi i+2\pi j\right)+\left(j-i\right)\sin\left(\left(i+j\right)t_{1}w\right)+\left(i+j\right)\sin\left(\left(j-i\right)t_{1}w\right)}{2\left(i^{2}-j^{2}\right)w}.
$$

*Case 2.* If $i=j$, then

$$
\eqalign{
I &= \frac{1}{2w}\int_{wt_{1}}^{w\left(t_{1}+\frac{2\pi}{w}\right)}\cos\left(\left(2j\right)u\right)du+\frac{1}{2w}\int_{wt_{1}}^{w\left(t_{1}+\frac{2\pi}{w}\right)}\cos\left(\left(j-j\right)u\right)du \cr
&= \frac{1}{2w}\int_{wt_{1}}^{w\left(t_{1}+\frac{2\pi}{w}\right)}\cos\left(\left(2j\right)u\right)du+\frac{1}{2w}\int_{wt_{1}}^{w\left(t_{1}+\frac{2\pi}{w}\right)}1du \cr
&= \frac{\sin\left(2wt_{1}j+4\pi j\right)-\sin\left(2wt_{1}j\right)}{4wj}+\frac{\pi}{w}. \cr
}
$$

If someone could find a more general result without having to result in cases, that would be great.

Here is a Desmos link in case you want to convince yourself my messy work works: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ewn8dpslou